# OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: nested asn1 error

Tags: ruby, openssl

I am trying to convert string to rsa public key in ruby.

```
str = "some string"
OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n#{str}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----")
```

I executed in my system, it is working fine but when i tried to execute on my remote server, its throwing error OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: nested asn1 error. I even updated my openssl version, its OpenSSL 1.0.2o

Comment: Your certificate is malformed. PEM uses `\r\n`. Also see [RFC 1421, Privacy Enhancement for Internet Electronic Mail](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1421), Section 9 Descriptive Grammar and Section 4.3.1 Constraints. Once you fix the line endings, `"some string"` should fail to parse. The certifcate data needs to be ASN.1 encoded, not ASCII strings.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your input string has no carriage returns. I had this problem and replacing all "\r\n" newlines with just "\n" fixed the problem.

Comment: PEM uses `\r\n`. If you encounter a library that cannot consume `\r\n` then you should probably file a bug report. Also see [RFC 1421, Privacy Enhancement for Internet Electronic Mail](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1421), Section 9 Descriptive Grammar and Section 4.3.1 Constraints.